# how to display preview of fonts from server in android studio

Tags: java, android

how to display a ttf file using link from server like as .png or .jpg etc

i Know how to download and load from file

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how to load the font from a file You can do other task by making a private folder to store that font files on the user's device and then load that font from the file. But first I don't think it is possible to load fonts from user storage to your TextView but even as you said you know how to load it from a file, so you can follow the above steps to do your task but it will be very bad and ram-consuming for the user's device because your app will create a new object for every font he wants to show and consider every font will first download and store at the user device. So in results your app data loading will be too slow.

So instead I will suggest you to store a preview image of that font on your backend and load that image into ImageView with glide or Picasso.